# C++ Implementing threads with Inter thread communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

im currently attempting to create server and client application that use winsock, with a  main program I need to have a second thread to always be listening for data.

This communication is non blocking. I am really having trouble in finding a way of communicating between threads, an example of what im looking for is: Server sends a string to the client e.g. "viewData" and this kind of information will be fetched by the main thread and then a specific function may also be called.

Here is an example of my thread, i am creating this using `_beginthread( (void(*)(void*))SocketReceive, 0, (void*)&ohuman );`

```
//thread focused on listening to connection
void  SocketReceive( comms* ohuman)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    int inDataLength;
    std::string contents;

    for(;;)
    {
        if(!ohuman->getGameOn()) 
        {
            // Display message from server
            memset(buffer,0,999);
            inDataLength=recv((INT_PTR)ohuman->getSocket(),buffer,1000,0);
            contents = std::string(buffer); //create a string from the char array for easy access
            //only display if we get some content

            if(inDataLength > 0)
            {
                //???DealWithMessage(

            int nError=WSAGetLastError();

            if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
            {
                std::cout<<"Winsock error code: "<<nError<<"\r\n";
                std::cout<<"Server disconnected!\r\n";
                // Shutdown our socket
                shutdown((INT_PTR)ohuman->getSocket(),0x01);
                // Close our socket entirely
                closesocket((INT_PTR)ohuman->getSocket());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    _endthread();

}
```

I also saw this site  which is supposed to help out with ITC, any advice on this-> 
http://derkarl.org/itc/

With a straightforward main loop, I am interested in any approach that might work, I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days with no luck, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to go to the trouble of raising an extra thread to connect to the server and listen for recv data, why are you using a non-blocking design?  The above for(;;) seems like it uses up one core doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a shared variable(with locks around it) and both threads poll/write to it, or you can register [callback functions](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) between the threads and call the other thread on some event.